# Regex: Matching multiple spaces doesn't work

Tags: regex, sed

I have this content in file:

```
  core        = 7.x
  base theme  = adaptivetheme
  release     = 7.x-3.x
  engine      = phptemplate
```

I'm tring to get everything after: `base theme  =` to the end of line, so I would like to get `adaptivetheme` .

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24151/37309 I'm trying to do:

```
sed -n 's/base\stheme\s+=\s//p' file
sed -n 's/base\stheme += //p' file
```

But it doesn't work. However this does work:

```
sed -n 's/base\stheme  = //p' file
```

So what I'm doing wrong? I would like to match it regardless of number of spaces that there can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -n 's/base theme \+= //p' file
```

This says "one or more spaces" (that's the meaning of the escaped `\+`).

By itself, `sed` uses only the basic Regex (BRE). If you want to use [extended regex](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html) some rules change - like what characters need to be escaped or not. You can invoke the extended mode with the `-r` flag. Then the `+` no longer needs to be escaped.

These dialects of regex are very confusing. I keep having to look it up myself, too...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-r`-flag for extended regex-support:

```
sed -r 's/base\stheme\s+=\s//'
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggested solution will print out the other lines in the file without modification. You need the `-n` flag to suppress output, and the `p` at the end of the command to print out lines where the match is found.